# Insert string in one column if a value is present in another column

Tags: python-3.x, string, dataframe, replace

Using Python3, trying to replace the blank cell in col 'EWIS Comp Type' with 'CONNECTOR' if there is a value, other than 'nan', in the corresponding cell of 'Srch1'.

Oh and this cannot rewrite over the entire 'EWIS Comp Type' column as there is other data not pictured; only fill in for blanks when 'Srch1' has an entry as stated above.

Apologies if not in ideal format and/or proper terminology, new to Stackoverflow and coding.

Thanks in advance

What I am starting with:

[image: What I am starting with]

df['EWIS Comp Type'].fillna(df.Srch1, inplace=True)

df['EWIS Comp Type'].str.replace(r'P[0-9]+', 'CONNECTOR', regex=True)    #would not change the PXXX to CONNECTOR

also tried,

df['EWIS Comp Type'].re.sub(r'P[0-9]+', 'CONNECTOR',str)  #this errored which I had no luck researching the fix

I can get the PXXX to replicate to 'EWIS Comp Type', but cannot seem to get the PXXX to be replaced by 'CONNECTOR'.

What Im trying to have happen:

[image: What I am trying to accomplish]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you again Andrej K. for your help.  The below seems to work:

```
df.loc[df['Srch1'].notna() & df['EWIS Comp Type'].isna(), 'EWIS Comp Type'] = 'CONNECTOR'
df['EWIS Comp Type'].fillna('', inplace=True)
df.loc[df['Srch1'].notna() & (df['EWIS Comp Type'].str.find('CONNECTOR')<0), 'EWIS Comp Type'] = df['EWIS Comp Type'] + ', CONNECTOR'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```py
df.loc[df["Srch1"].notna(), "EWIS Comp Type"] = "CONNECTOR"
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
  EWIS Comp Type Srch1
0      CONNECTOR  P471
1      CONNECTOR  P467
2                  NaN
3                  NaN
```

---

EDIT: To populate only values which are empty (`""`):

```py
df.loc[df["Srch1"].notna() & df["EWIS Comp Type"].eq(""), "EWIS Comp Type"] = "CONNECTOR"
```

Comment: That works as you showed, but it overwrote existing data in the ‘EWIS Comp Type’ col.  I need it to populate ‘EWIS Comp Type’ only when it’s blank/nan and Srch1 is populated.  But thank you for your quick response!!

Comment: Another attempt I made was to replicate the Pxxx from Srch1 using df['EWIS Comp Type'].fillna(df.Srch1, inplace=True).   But I couldn’t figure out how to replace the Pxxx with ‘connector’

Comment: Apologies for the delayed follow-up.  The edited version would overwrite existing content in the 'EWIS Comp Type' col.  I posted below what worked.  Thank you very much for your time and help!!!